# php_curl does not work when I try and install Magento

Tags: php, magento, wampserver

I have Apache version 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.13. When I try to install Magento it just keeps telling me that curl must be loaded. I have tried to troubleshoot the problem but nothing has solved it. I've done the following:

1. uncomment php_curl.dll in php.ini file (both in php/ext and the apache/bin folders)
2. When that didn't work I downloaded two versions of php_ curl fix files (5.3.13 and 5.4.3) and used each to replace the original php_curl.dll file in php/ext.
   With 5.4.3 I got the error message that "curl failed to start because the side-by-side configuration is incorrect". Now the 5.3.13 version is in the folder but I get two error messages "Program can't start because php5.dll is missing from your computer" and "ext/php_curl.dll - the specified module could not be found'.

Could someone give me further advice, because at this point I'm clueless on what to do next? I am using wampserver 2.2 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that more people are having this problem - php_curl.dll is badly compiled and doesn't work under Win7/8 64-bit versions.

I found this topic in official Wamp Server forums and it looks like people provided some answers there:
[Wamp Server 2.2 Windows 7 64-bit and curl not working side-by-side configuration incorrect](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,85716,112949)

Comment: I've installed wampserver 2.4 32 bit. That solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Update your PHP version to 7.0 or higher.
They have fix the php-curl in >7.0 version see the artical [php Chang log](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.1.11)